# Dynamically load data

Tags: 8, hooks, webforms

I'm trying to load some data for a select in webform. But for some reasons, I can't trigger the hook.

this is the url where I think the hook should trigger :

> /admin/structure/webform/config/options/manage/data_liste

I'm using Webform Version : 8.x-5.16 and drupal 8

```
function module_alterwebform_webform_select_options_info(){
  $items = array();
  if(function_exists('_get_data')) {
    $items['data_liste'] = array(
      'title' => t('Liste'),
      'options callback' => '_get_data',
    );
  }

  return $items;
}

function _get_data() {
  $options = array();
  $options['key'] = 'value';
  return $options;
}
```

Comment: There are many reasons for which a hook isn't triggered, starting from the fact that Drupal core modules or third-party modules don't see that function as hook implementation, which could happen (for example) because the function name doesn't start with the module machine name, or because the second half of the function name isn't correct for that hook. Why do you think that hook would be invoked by visiting /admin/structure/webform/config/options/manage/data_liste?

Comment: Are you sure the hook isn't invoked only when a module is installed, and the result cached? That what Drupal core itself did with `hook_menu()`, in Drupal 7. Did you edit the module code after installing it? The code of installed modules should not be edited before uninstalling them, or Drupal core will not notice the module has new hooks, as that information is cached.

Comment: I didn't any webform module. I've created my module, called the hook. I've also search in the file **webform.api.php** (where there's a list of hook) to see if I had to change mine, but couldn't make any hook of any kind work. For the url, the hook i'm trying to add is a dynamic list, so basicaly I thought that the page where is listed the options of the select should be what I what looking for